# My data is not going through php, how to fix it?

Tags: php, html, ajax

My data sent by ajax is not going through the php file. The data is going but there is no response data ..
I am sending some form data to the php to render it but the data is stuck and php file not recieving it.

```
  $('#formSubmit').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var uniqid =  sessionStorage.getItem("uniqID");
      var category = $('#Selectcat option:selected').html();
      var perannum = $("#perannum").val();
      var adharno = $("#adharno").val();
      var adharname = $("#adharname").val();

       $.ajax({
       url: "Process/Register2.php",
        type: "POST",
          data:"uniqID=" +uniqid+ "&category=" +category+ "&perannum=" +perannum+ "&adharno=" +adharno+ "&adharname=" +adharname,
      contentType: false,
       cache: false,
    processData:false,
    beforeSend : function()
    {
      },
        success: function(data)
                                {

      if(jQuery.trim(data) == "1"){
          window.location = "Register3.html";
      }
  }

  });
       });
```

my php -

```
  <?php 

      include_once("Config.php");

     if(isset($_POST['category'])){
           echo 'got it';
       }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> contentType: false,
> ```

Don't do that. You **want** jQuery's default content-type when you're sending form-encoded data.

---

For best practices:

Pass an object to jQuery instead of encoding the data manually (currently, you are not escaping anything that might need to be escaped)

```
data: {
    uniqID: uniqid, 
    category: category, 
    perannum: perannum,
    adharno: adharno,
    adharname: adharname
},
```

and allow jQuery to process it into properly encoded data by removing:

> ```
> processData:false
> ```